# Trying to count frequency of words in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have an excel sheet that has many actions in a study, one of those actions is "chat". I need to simply count frequency of words in these chats.

creating a 2 column sheet to filter out anything but chats

```
Chatlog <- Event_Log_IP_4_20_2010_9_22_48_1_%>% 
  select(EventName, EventDetails) %>% 
  filter (EventName == "Chat") %>% 
  view()
```

creating a 1 column sheet that is just our chatlog

```
text <- Chatlog %>% 
  select(EventDetails) %>% 
  view()
```

So I now have a column called "EventDetails" with my 156 separate chats
[view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oqr0G.png)

I got this from this website:

```
text_df <- text_df %>% 
 mutate_all(as.character) %>% 
 unnest_tokens(word, text)
```

It gives me an error, But it still seems to work.

[I get this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7vUX.png)

This seems like exactly what I'm looking for initially, but it has 118000 entries when there is only 750 words in my dataframe.

Am I going completely down the wrong path or is there just a solvable bug?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to count the words in a data frame column, you can do this in base R with `table` after splitting on the space:

```
# example data 
df <- data.frame(text = c("This is", "an example", "of some example words"))

table(unlist(strsplit(df$text, " ")))
```

Output

```
# an example      is      of    some    This   words 
#  1       2       1       1       1       1       1
```

If you want your output in a data frame:

```
as.data.frame(table(unlist(strsplit(df$text, " "))))

#      Var1 Freq
# 1      an    1
# 2 example    2
# 3      is    1
# 4      of    1
# 5    some    1
# 6    This    1
# 7   words    1
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using `tidytext` library with `unnest_tokens`.

Here's an example data.frame based on your image (we prefer data posted using `dput()` instead of images.

```
df <- data.frame(
  EventDetails = c(
    "ok lets try",
    "sorry for the all caps",
    "want to try for like 18 this time",
    "are you lights and are you talking to me"
  )
)
```

When you call `unnest_tokens`, you specify the output (here I chose "word" but could use anything), input (that's the column name that has the text, in this case "EventDetails"), and token (looks like you just want "words" instead of "sentences", "lines", or "paragraphs").

That will result in one row per word. If you want to count up words (frequencies of words), you can use "count" from `dplyr` and `sort = TRUE` to order the words by frequency (highest at the top).

```
library(tidytext)
library(dplyr)

df |>
  unnest_tokens(
    output = word, 
    input = EventDetails, 
    token = "words") |>
  count(word, sort = TRUE)
```

**Output**

```
      word n
1      are 2
2      for 2
3       to 2
4      try 2
5      you 2
6       18 1
7      all 1
8      and 1
9     caps 1
10    lets 1
11  lights 1
12    like 1
13      me 1
14      ok 1
15   sorry 1
16 talking 1
17     the 1
18    this 1
19    time 1
20    want 1
```